# How to add holidays to kendo scheduler?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Is anybody know how to add holidays to kendo scheduler?

I mean in a holiday user shouldn't be able to add any events.

Comment: BorHunter, before asking a question, stackoverflow suggests to do a basic search about the topic you are focusing on... Please search kendo's documentation and if it doesn't provide you a clear enough answer, then edit your question here.

Comment: @Armfoot I was searching web & checking the documentation, nothing

Comment: @BorHunter from "user mustn't be add any events" do you mean user shoudn't be able to add event on that particular holiday/date ?

Comment: @machun yes, you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to add a custom class in my example i created class **k-holiday** or maybe utilize kendo class **k-non-workhour** and on dataBound function add this :

```
dataBound: function () {
    var scheduler = this;
    //get scheduler view
    var schedulerView = this.view();
    //loop through all slot/event/tile
    schedulerView.table.find("td[role=gridcell]").each(function () {

        //find start date
        var slot = scheduler.slotByElement($(this));

        var CONSTANT_HOLIDAY_DATE = new Date("2013/6/11");
        CONSTANT_HOLIDAY_DATE.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        slot.startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

        //compare date curent event with holiday
        if (slot.startDate.getTime() == CONSTANT_HOLIDAY_DATE.getTime()) {
            $(this).addClass("k-holiday");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("k-holiday");

        }
    });
},
```

i created a holiday on this particular Date `new Date("2013/6/11")` where later on all event/slot on this date will have **k-holiday** class, then you want to add this to your edit function :

```
edit: function (e) {
    var uid = e.container.attr('data-uid');
          var element = e.sender.element.find('div.k-event[data-uid="' + uid + '"]');
    var slot =$("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler").slotByElement(element);
    if($(slot.element).hasClass("k-holiday")){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

above condition will filter event that is double clicked / edited , where it will prevent the event that has k-holiday to open the popup. Please refer to this [kendo dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/eQemO)

Note : on that example you will notice that on **tuesday 6/11** you can't trigger the edit/add new event, but on the day other than that you still can

Comment: you know how to adding holidays in Kendo UI in Angular 6?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [all day event template](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#configuration-allDayEventTemplate) to create holidays.

The message can be set through [messages.allDay](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#configuration-messages.allDay) like this:

```
<div id="scheduler"></div>
<script>
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
  date: new Date("2013/6/6"),
  messages: {
    allDay: "Holiday"
  },
  dataSource: [
    {
      id: 1,
      start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"),
      end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"),
      title: "Interview"
    }
  ]
});
</script>
```

You can check [this executable example](http://dojo.telerik.com/uFune) with holiday details.

### Edit

> [BorHunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2733661/borhunter): but in your example I can add new events into scheduler, but I don't need it. I mean user shoudn't be able to add event on that particular holiday/date.

Then you just disable that option by using [editable](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#configuration-editable) like [this example](http://dojo.telerik.com/enArE) that has:

```
editable: false,
```

Or [this one](http://dojo.telerik.com/upOhE/2):

```
editable: {
  create: false,
  update: false,
  resize: false,
  move: false,
  destroy: false
},
```

Comment: but in your example I can add new events into scheduler, but I don't need it. I mean user shoudn't be able to add event on that particular holiday/date.

Comment: @BorHunter I have edited my answer for not allowing to add more events into the scheduler, as you requested.

Comment: How to adding holidays in kendo Angular 6?